# How to get the char data type from mysql using resultset

Tags: java, api, jdbc, resultset

I have been doing CRUD operation on database, but i could not find any direct method for the getting the data type `char` in database.

Though i achieved the output using the `getString(String column_name)` of the result set, but i wonder why there does not exist any method like `getChar(String column_name)`, since String and Character are two different data types.

Comment: Just take the first character of the string, given it's not null or empty of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Refer to the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm#CHDBJAGH) and see the table 3-1 and you will get decent idea that why there does not exists `getChar(String column_name)`.

**Summary:** Mapping of char is to String. So there exists `getString(String column_name)` for the char data type

Answer (score 23):

As MySQL sees it, it's all `Strings` because it has no type for a single character. Sure, you can set `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` to sizes of max one, but this is a special case and you generally don't want to make methods for special cases when the functionality is already there.

Just extract the Java `char` from the resulting `String`, as such:

```
getString(column_name).charAt(0)
```

Answer (score 5):

It is because  a [Char](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) in MySQL doesn't really mean a singular char value, it really means a array of chars.  In java an array of chars is represented as a String, hence the same method.

Answer (score 1):

Databases often have only one type for representing all the strings of characters.

A char is only a special case: a string with one character, so it would not be really useful to add this type.

And don't be fooled by their name like CHAR. :)

Answer (score -1):

When the data from table is just one character (CHAR type),
I use like this in Java program.

```
    String str=rs.getString("column_name").toString();
```